What is exactly "spin of atom"?
$$E_{\text{ex}}=-2 J_{\text{ex}} \mathbf{S}_i \mathbf{S}_j =-2 J  \mathbf{S}_i \mathbf{S}_j \text{cos}\phi$$
I'm studying magnetism and often see sentences like "spin $i$ product spin $j$" things.
The image I captured is an example. It is about exchange interaction in ferromagnetism.
So, what is exactly a "spin S" in those sentences?
First, I don't think it is spin angular momentum of a electron.
Free electron moves around metal, so it couldn't be seem like "arrow attached in space"
Second, it can't be spin angular momentum of a nucleus neither.
I heard that spin of nucleus is very small, because it is consisted of protons and neutrons which have opposite spins.
Finally, is it a sum of a atom's whole ingredient?
It is large and attached in space, so it makes sense.
But can exchange interaction occurs between two entire atoms?
I thought it occurs between two electrons, of two protons, or something very simple things.
What is the answer? If you can give me some paper or article, I'll be thankful.

Please use MathJax for writing formulas.

I recently gave an answer to a somewhat similar question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/806845/247642

"First, I don't think it is spin angular momentum of a electron. Free electron moves around metal, so it couldn't be seem like "arrow attached in space"" - Your second sentence is not an argument for the first - there's lots of electrons in metals that are not free!

$\mathbf{S}_i \mathbf{S}_j$ Isn’t the product supposed to be a dot product of the spin vectors?

First up, ferromagnetism comes mainly from electron spin, with a small contribution from orbital angular momentum. The nucleus has no significant effect on it, as far as I am aware, and therefore should not contribute in the exchange interaction. However, this is as far as I will go explaining magnetism to you - Any undergraduate textbook on condensed matter physics will do a much better job at it than me.
What I will try to explain to you is what spin is, or at least, clean up some misconceptions you might have about it. Spin is not angular momentum. It is simply property of particles which only becomes significant when dealing with them on the quantum scale, and happens to have a very similar mathematical description to angular momentum - classical angular momentum is described by rotations in 3D real space (the group $\text{SO}(3)$) while spin is described by the group $\text{SU}(2)$, which is, in simple terms, isomorphic to two copies of $\text{SO}(3)$ (mathematicians say that it is a double cover). The difference between spin and other fundamental qualities of particles like mass or charge is that spin is interpreted as a direction instead of a magnitude, which is why it is commonly modeled as a vector - an "arrow in space" as you put it. It does not need to be attached to anything to exist, the free electrons in the crystal lattice of a metal all have a spin. So to answer your question what the spin $\textbf{S}_j$ means in your equation: It is simply an operator measuring (or representing, depending on what you are calculating) the direction of the spin of an electron participating in the exchange.

Hi Paulina, I'm curious what you mean by "Spin is not angular momentum". Is this something new people are saying?

The way I learned it, is that while the mathematical descriptions of spin and angular momentum are similar, one should not think of particles actually rotating in space.

That's what I thought you were getting at. We physicists are not as precise with our terms as we should be. I think one should consider that if we define angular momentum (AM) as that quantity that is conserved because of the rotational invariance of our physics (Noether's theoem), then spin AM, orbital AM, and classical AM are all under the same umbrella.

The intrinsic spin of an electron really is angular momentum, but it's different to classical angular momentum because it's purely axial, with no orbital component. Also, it's quantised, so it defies our classical intuition when we measure it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere

@PM2Ring the properties you state about spin having no orbital component and being quantized are precisely the reasons why I am insistent that spin is not angular momentum. Yes, it does behave like it in some aspects, and behaves wildly different in others. One should not confuse mathematical descriptions with physical reality.

Spin really is a kind of angular momentum. Its not just a mathematical resemblance, it's physical. Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/594504/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/203792/123208
